# How to put a changing value inside an url?

Tags: php, url

Currently I have a curl script that scrapes information from this url.

```
$url = 'https://www.marktplaats.nl' . '/q/iphone/p/1/#offeredSince:Gisteren/';
```

Is it possible to automatically scrape information from more links?
For example to also scrape page 2, 3, 4, 5 etc. at the same time, when I set some variable to 5 etc.

```
https://www.marktplaats.nl/q/iphone/p/1/#offeredSince:Gisteren/
https://www.marktplaats.nl/q/iphone/p/2/#offeredSince:Gisteren/
https://www.marktplaats.nl/q/iphone/p/3/#offeredSince:Gisteren/
https://www.marktplaats.nl/q/iphone/p/4/#offeredSince:Gisteren/
https://www.marktplaats.nl/q/iphone/p/5/#offeredSince:Gisteren/
```

My cURL script supports scraping 1 url. But not multiple.

```
declare(strict_types = 1);
set_time_limit(0);
ob_start();

include 'functions.php';

$curl = curl_init();

$url = 'https://www.marktplaats.nl' . '/q/iphone/p/1/#offeredSince:Gisteren/';

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($curl);

$advertisements = array();

preg_match_all('\/a\/.*?.*?.html', $result, $links);
$advertisements = $links[0];
```

I want an 'option' that lets me scrape multiple links by setting a changeable value for the page number.

EDIT before I figured it out:

This is my current code. Do I need to use curl_multi_init for this, and how does that work then?

```
<?php 
declare(strict_types = 1);
set_time_limit(0);
ob_start();

include 'functions.php';

$curl = curl_init();

$url = 'https://www.marktplaats.nl' . '/q/laptoptas/p/18/#offeredSince:Gisteren/';

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($curl);

$advertisements = array();

// regex for advertisement links
preg_match_all('%\/a\/.*?.*?.html%', $result, $links);
$advertisements = $links[0];

// encode the array into a JSON string
$encodedString = json_encode($advertisements, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

$decodedArray = json_decode($encodedString, true);
$decodedArray = array_values(array_unique($decodedArray, SORT_REGULAR));

$content = null;
foreach($decodedArray as $link) {
    $content .= "https://marktplaats.nl" . $link . PHP_EOL;
}
file_put_contents('advertisements.txt', $content, FILE_APPEND);

$bestand = file('advertisements.txt');
$bestand = array_unique($bestand);

file_put_contents('advertisements.txt', $bestand);
```

EDIT after I figured it out:
Well, as you can read. I figured it out. Thanks to l'L'l, for providing me with the right loop!

```
<?php 
declare(strict_types = 1);
set_time_limit(0);
ob_start();

include 'functions.php';

$curl = curl_init();

for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    $url = 'https://www.marktplaats.nl' . '/q/iphone/p/' . $i . '/#offeredSince:Gisteren/';

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    $advertisements = array();

    // regex for advertisement links
    preg_match_all('%\/a\/.*?.*?.html%', $result, $links);
    $advertisements = $links[0];

    // encode the array into a JSON string
    $encodedString = json_encode($advertisements, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

    $decodedArray = json_decode($encodedString, true);
    $decodedArray = array_values(array_unique($decodedArray, SORT_REGULAR));

    $content = null;
    foreach($decodedArray as $link) {
        $content .= "https://marktplaats.nl" . $link . PHP_EOL;
    }

    file_put_contents('advertisements.txt', $content, FILE_APPEND);

    $bestand = file('advertisements.txt');
    $bestand = array_unique($bestand);

    file_put_contents('advertisements.txt', $bestand);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `for loop` should work:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    $url = 'https://www.marktplaats.nl' . '/q/iphone/p/' . $i . '/#offeredSince:Gisteren/';
    ...
}
```

↳ https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. I think it's more difficult then my first impression.

Comment: When I put my code in your for loop the script still only scrapes from 1 url. Is there any place I can show you that code? Because it's too long for a comment.

Comment: I figured it out by putting all of the needed code inside the for loop. Thanks for your quick answer and helping me out. I appreciate it!